# Bootstrap Nav Bar Not Responsive on smaller devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html, which features a bootstrap nav bar. As you can see, there is a menu item called "Coverage" with one link called "Add Coverage". This works fine on larger screens, but when I resize to make it smaller, as expected the Toggle navigation appears. When I click this and the menu expands to show everything, the Funds, Intraday Orders, and Reports still work fine, however clicking on the Coverage item does NOT result in the Add Coverage link being shown. Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { goHome = "true" })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-header">                    
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left menu-item-spacing">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Analysts", "Index", "Analyst")</li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Coverage<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Coverage", "AddCoverageSearch", "Coverage")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Funds", "List", "Holding", null, null)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Intraday Orders", "Account", "Blotter", new { analystname = @user.UserName }, null)</li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-sxm">Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

HTML created is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="/?goHome=true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-header">                    
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left menu-item-spacing">
                    <li><a href="/Analyst">Analysts</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Coverage<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/Coverage/Coverage?status=A">All Coverage</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Coverage/CoverageAssignments?groupingBySector=True">Coverage Assignments</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Holding/PortfolioCoverage">Portfolio Coverage</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Holding/PortfolioSnapshot">Portfolio Snapshot</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Writeup/WriteupSections?status=A">Writeup Sections</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/Holding/List">Funds</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Blotter/Account?analystname=Scott%20Mabry">Intraday Orders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-sxm">Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: When I plop your code into Bootply the "Coverage" dropdown functions as expected.  Are you sure the `@Html.ActionLink()` is outputting the correct code?

Comment: Yes, the outputted code is the same if I am at full size, or small.

Comment: Perhaps if you shared what the compiled HTML looks like?

Comment: I added it above.

Comment: Two things (1) You do NOT need `.pull-left` in your nav; its' actually causing an issue on mobile.  (2) is what is output under `Coverage` everything that SHOULD be pulled from `@Html.ActionLink("Add Coverage", "AddCoverageSearch", "Coverage")` ?

Comment: I removed pull-left but now each dropdown options is displayed in a "staircase" fashion, that is, each is staggered a bit to the right of the other on smaller screens. As for the ActionLink, the code is the same when the screen size is large, and it works there.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the code you've presented seems very atypical for Bootstrap.  For example, you have your `.navbar-toggle` inside a duplicate of `.navbar-header` which also houses your `.collapse`.

If you were to restructure your Navbar component to better match the recommendations and styles of Bootstrap 3.x you would use code like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#null"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
      
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#null">Analysts</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Coverage<span class="caret"></span></a>
        
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#null">All Coverage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#null">Coverage Assignments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#null">Portfolio Coverage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#null">Portfolio Snapshot</a></li>
        <li><a href="#null">Writeup Sections</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#null">Funds</a></li>
      <li><a href="#null">Intraday Orders</a></li>
      <li><a href="#null">Reports</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In the above code every link under `.dropdown-menu` appears as expected.  The entire navigational menu collapses on smaller screens, again as expected.  If the above code results in a different result when inserted into your project I would suspect the problem is some additional CSS or JavaScript that is in conflict.

Two Caveats I would offer:

(1) The above code assumes you're using Bootstrap 3.x.  This is based on some of the classes called in your code which do not exist in 4.x.  If you're using 4.x that might also be causing some of your problems as the structure for the Navbar component has changed.

(2) For the purposes of a minified example I've removed a lot of additional styles or references to classes that aren't part of Bootstrap.  I've also removed the `class="dropdown-toggle hidden-sxm"` from under the "Reports" link as that link is not a dropdown menu and `hidden-sxm` is not a Bootstrap class.

Comment: As you guessed, I had a setting causing the error, which was to float all .nav li a to the left. This isn't needed, and removing it fixed the problem. But thanks also for the reminder of keeping the Bootstrap being used in sync with the actual Bootstrap css.